# Move error when matching an option inside a recursion

Tags: recursion, rust, match, lifetime

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the difference between 2 lines of code in this simple linked list implementation (inside the match statement in the `get_last` function).

```
struct Node {
    next_node: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn get_next(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Self> {
        self.next_node.as_deref_mut()
    }

    fn get_last(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        match self.get_next() {
            // Issue is here
            // The following compiles:
            Some(_) => self.get_next().unwrap().get_last(),
            
            // The following does not compile: 
            // Some(node) => node.get_last(),

            // What is the difference?

            None => self,
        }
    }
}
```

In the get_last function, I want to return the last element of the list. I do a recursion by matching the next element and then getting its last element.

By using `Some(node)`, I was expecting `node` to be equivalent to `self.get_next().unwrap()`, and to be able to use it just like in the commented line. Yet this does not compile as I get the following error:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `self` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:14:21
   |
10 |       fn get_last(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
   |                   ---------
   |                   |
   |                   binding `self` declared here
   |                   let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
11 |           match self.get_next() {
   |           -     --------------- borrow of `*self` occurs here
   |  _________|
   | |
12 | |             //Some(_) => self.get_next().unwrap().get_last(),
13 | |             Some(node) => node.get_last(),
14 | |             None => self,
   | |                     ^^^^ move out of `self` occurs here
15 | |         }
   | |_________- returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
```

You can also look at it online here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a1ed62b6e418bfee1bbc599b9ffb1500

It seems very weird to me as the 2 lines in the match look completely equivalent.

Comment: Classic Polonius problem (NLL case #3).

Comment: In short: this is a known limitation of the current borrow checker.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know about NLL. I add a link with a further explanation that helped me to understand NLL case #3: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md#problem-case-3-conditional-control-flow-across-functions